# how to incrase or decrease the brighness of the screen on button click

Tags: android, screen-brightness

in my android app i want a  single button in which 
on 1st click brightness will be 10 ,
on 2nd click brightness will be 50 ,
on third click brightness will be 255 (full )
 as the user click next it will back to 10 again 
how to code this i have tired this solution but only able to increase

```
 private void getBrightness() {
    try 
        {   int curBrightnessValue = 0 ;
            curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            if(curBrightnessValue >= 250  ) 
            {

            int SysBackLightValue = curBrightnessValue-30;


                   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                   android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                   SysBackLightValue);
                   curBrightnessValue=SysBackLightValue;
            }
            else if(curBrightnessValue <250)

            {

                 int SysBackLightValue = curBrightnessValue+30;


                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                   android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                   SysBackLightValue);
                   curBrightnessValue=SysBackLightValue;



            }
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I can't see where you set your brightness in your code, there is no set for 10,50,255 values in your code.

Comment: in this code i have tried to increase and decrease the brightness but its not working as per my requirement

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even do what you said you got in your question(you only try to increase and decrease by 30 without even applying it), you are getting the Brightness the right way, and all you have to do is to handle the new value in your Button Click Listener:

```
    private int getBrightness() {
        int curBrightnessValue = 0 ;
         try 
            {   
              curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            }
        catch(Exception ex){
              curBrightnessValue = 0
            }
        return curBrightnessValue;
    }

    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            int current_brightness = getBrightness();
            int new_brightness;
            if(current_brightness > 250)
                 new_brightness = 10;
            else if(current_brightness >= 50)
                 new_brightness = 255;
            else if(current_brightness >= 10)
                 new_brightness = 50;
            else
                 new_brightness = 150; // let's say this will be the default value
           // and to set the brightness
           set_system_brightness(new_brightness);
         }
    });

    private void set_system_brightness(int new_brightness){
        Settings.System
        .putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                new_brightness); // Set the system
                            // brightness
        android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams w_lp = getWindow()
                .getAttributes(); // Get the current window
                                    // attributes
        w_lp.screenBrightness = new_brightness / (float) 255; // Set
                                                        // the
                                                        // brightness
                                                        // of
                                                        // this
                                                        // window
        getWindow().setAttributes(w_lp); // Apply attribute
                                            // changes to
                                            // this window
    }
```